# How do i create and populate a linked list using classes in c++?

Tags: c++, class, linked-list

I am trying to create a program which uses classes to create a linked list data structure.  Is it necessary to create one linked list class which contains the list in it's entirety: nodes with info and the list? or do i create a  class for the list and a class for the nodes in the list?

Thanks,

Comment: Usually you want separate classes for a node and for an entire list.

Comment: I am working with multiple files, would it be necessary or better to create multiple files for the list and the node classes (.cpp and .h) or just have  linkedList.cpp and linkedList.h which houses both classes?

Comment: The node class is typically done as a nested class inside the linked-list class, so they typically reside in the same file(s).

Comment: it makes sense intuitively but i figured either way was possible thanks for the help

Comment: You're right: it *is* possible to create the node class outside the linked list class -- it's just a lot less common, and rarely accomplishes much.

Comment: As far as data members go for the list is it possible to populate each node with different types of classes? ex: car class truck class in a list of automobiles

Comment: Generally no. If you want polymorphism, the list will need to store (smart) pointers to objects instead of storing the objects directly.

Comment: Use templates to make the nodes adjust to any type.  Prefer to use `std::list`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't create your own list - use [std::list](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/)